# namespace specification says uri is not registered in android studio

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am trying to add screen change functionality to a project. However when I try to add the main layout to the layout_land directory, the copy has the error

URI is not registered

on the namespace specification.

I need to replace the root element with a frame layout but can't specify the namespace to use.

What do I need to do to make this basic functionality work?

Again, any help ...

Here is the code.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="24dp"

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/true_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/true_button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/false_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/false_button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/next_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:text="@string/next_button"
                android:gravity="right" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: IIRC, the error should be showing you the exact line where the unrecognized namespace appears. What line is it?

Comment: Line 2 <FrameLayout xmlns:...

Comment: This happens with original activity_main as well